# How do I get IE and Firefox to respect the aria-hidden property?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on a portion of a website that uses a common symbol to denote a specific text, but don't want a screen reader to read the symbol, but instead describe what the symbol means.

For example:

> You'll get a free iPad∞.

Where ∞ means "If you win the contest". This text is displayed elsewhere on the site.

In the source, I have the following:

```html
You'll get a free iPad<acronym title="If you win the contest"><span aria-hidden="true">&#8734;</span></acronym>
```

This works fine in Chrome and correctly says "If you win the contest", but in Firefox and IE it reads ∞ as "Infinity".

Am I missing something that will help IE/Firefox to know what to do in this instance?

If it matters, I'm using Firefox 48.0.2, IE 11 and Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m

Comment: What happens if you don't have the acronym tag there? Does it still read out the infinity?

Comment: @BSMP Yes, it's not respecting the aria-hidden property at all.

Comment: [`<acronym>` is a non-standard tag.](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/acronym)  Please don't use it. (not that this helps in any way.  Just an FYI.)

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yeah, it was deprecated in favor of <abbr> in HTML5, but that part is legacy, and I've not been given leave to update it.

Comment: Can you modify the CSS?  As far as I know, an element having the property of `aria-hidden` doesn't automatically hide it.  it's probably a style rule like `[aria-hidden]{display:none}` or whatever.  In which case, it's probably just being overridden somewhere.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I just tried with a new HTML document without any stylesheets attached, and am getting the same behavior, so I don't think it's stylesheet related.

Comment: I think what they meant was you may need to add `[aria-hidden]{ display: none; }` to your stylesheet to make sure the element is truly "hidden" in those browsers.

Comment: I get it now... It's for the tooltip as you hover over the icon.  Browsers will usually display the title attribute in a little box.  Unfortunately I can't replicate that in my FF (also 48.0.2): http://i.stack.imgur.com/PoeEt.png

Comment: Also working in IE 11 for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gbPB0.png (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/072cLg1o/show/)

Comment: @JosephMarikle The problem in both of those cases is that the screen reader (in this case, NVDA) doesn't read the values from tooltip, and incorrectly says "Infinity"

Comment: The screen reader is not supposed to read the values from the `title` attribute (what you call a tool-tip). Are you just using NVDA? What about JAWS, VoiceOver, Narrator, and TalkBack (and maybe Orca, depending on your need)?

Comment: Firefox/NVDA does not read the infinity symbol. IE/NVDA does not read the infinity symbol but does read the `title` value. Chrome does not play well with NVDA. Pen: http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/VKPwrV

Comment: @aardrian The standard that I have to work to is that NVDA will provide the correct response, so yes, I'm only testing with NVDA. With the page that you posted, IE/Firefox behave the same, and NVDA says "infinity", while with Chrome NVDA says "If you win the contest"

Comment: NVDA users generally do not use Chrome. I would say "never," but sometimes they mis-click. Re-tested without the mouse (to be sure, since hovering causes the infinity to be announced). I am using NVDA 2016.2 and NVDA 2016.3. In Firefox 48.0.2 I hear "You'll get a free ipad if you win the contest." In IE11 I hear "You'll get a free ipad if you win the contest."

Comment: @aardrian I see what you're seeing now too...  If I hover, it says "infinity" in IE and Firefox, however if I just let it read the page it says the right thing in all cases. Out of curiosity, would someone using a screen reader typically allow it to read the screen? I'm really unfamiliar with accessibility testing.

Comment: Typically an SR user will navigate the page by keyboard, getting to the parts he or she wants and then letting it read. Jumping by headings, landmarks, lists, is common. A screen reader user will typically not be surfing with a mouse (not all SR users are completely blind).

Comment: Thank you. That helps me to understand better what I need to be focusing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the comments convo into an answer so it can be accepted (though the OP can do the same and accept his/her own answer).

- Firefox/NVDA does not read the infinity symbol.
- IE/NVDA does not read the infinity symbol but does read the title value.
- Chrome does not play well with NVDA.

Pen: http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/VKPwrV

NVDA users generally do not use Chrome. I would say "never," but sometimes they mis-click. Re-tested without the mouse (to be sure, since hovering causes the infinity to be announced). I am using NVDA 2016.2 and NVDA 2016.3. In Firefox 48.0.2 I hear "You'll get a free ipad if you win the contest." In IE11 I hear "You'll get a free ipad if you win the contest."

If you hove over the symbol with a (mouse) pointer, then the screen reader will announce it.

Typically an SR user will navigate the page by keyboard, getting to the parts he or she wants and then letting it read. Jumping by headings, landmarks, lists, etc, is common. A screen reader user will typically not be surfing with a mouse (but not all SR users are completely blind).

My suggestion is that you can leave your code as is (though replace the `<acronym>` with `<abbr>`).